# Is the Origen Git API and the test_ids gem configurable to use branches other than master?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am using the [test_ids gem](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids) to assign bins and when I try to publish, it always seems to push to master.  Is this configurable?  Pushing to master is not allowed in our environment, we use a dev branch.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of an alternative branch is not considered at all currently I'm afraid, this is something that you would need to add.

Most of the Git interaction is handled by this class - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids/blob/master/lib/test_ids/git.rb